# How to check if a char is in a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, char, function-definition

Ok, I feel this should be extraordinarily simple, but for the life of me I can not figure it out. I'm trying to write a function to find a char in a string for a hangman program. So for I've came up with :

```
int drawHangman(char trY, string wordA)
{ 
        int wrongTries = 0,            
    if(wordA.find(trY) != string::npos)     //checking to see if char is in word
            wrongTries++;           //if its not, ++
    else
        wrongTries = wrongTries;        //if it is, do wrong tries remains the same
    return wrongTries;                      //return # wrong tries
}
```

Suggetions?

Comment: So what's the problem you're having? Btw, `wrongTries = wrongTries` does nothing, you don't need that.

Comment: What is the `else` part supposed to accomplish? And how does the behavior of this code differ from the behavior you expect?

Comment: @Praetorian: As the comment says, it leaves `wrongTries` how it is. If only there were an easier way to do that.

Comment: Do you want to know _if_ the char appears in the string or _how many times_ it appears?

Comment: if `wordA.find(trY) != string::npos`, then the char IS in the word, so wrong tries should not be incremented

Comment: @user3596985 Are you trying to "check if a char is in a string" or to "find a char in a string"? (your question says both) - please clarify what you are trying to do and why you think your code is not good.

Comment: i just need to know if the char is in the string. after i get that info, it goes into a switch statement and prints out a board for the # of wrong tries. So far it only work for the first cin>>trY. also, I have an uppper&lower case checker in a different part of my code, but I appreciate the input. If it wasn't a massive amount of code I'd jut post it all haha. My program isn't keeping track of my wrongTries int and I was thinking it had something to do with this section of my code.

Answer (score 6):

You've already found how to check if a character is inside a given string (the `find` function). Just keep it simple :

```
bool isInside(const std::string & str, char c)
{
    return str.find(c) != std::string::npos;
}
```

Try to separate each task into a function that performs one simple thing. The function that finds if a character is in a given string should do nothing more than that. Counting how many times this function returns `false` is the matter of another function, since this is an unrelated task (unrelated to the search, that is).

Your `drawHangman` function should just focus on actually drawing the hangman, given through a parameter how many times the user failed, for instance.

Comment: Can I ask how this answer is getting bumped up when mine isn't and they are nearly identical, posted at nearly the same time, and I gave an example of the break down into separate functions?  Sorry if that sounds negative, not my intention, I'd like to be able to create better answers and I'm not understanding what I lack in my answer?

Comment: @BlackBird My guess is that you focused too much onto the code rather than onto the actual question. It has nothing to do with case sensitivity, as he solely wanted to know how to find a character in a string. Expanding into what he would want to do next also seems off-topic to me.

Comment: I understand that, thanks.  I don't feel the case sensitivity was too far of a stretch from the question though.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your correctly then what you need is the following

```
size_t drawHangman( const std::string &word, char c )
{ 
    static size_t wrongTries = 0;

    if ( word.find( c ) != std::string::npos )
    {
        return ( wrongTries = 0 );
    }
    else
    {
        return ( ++wrongTries );
    }
}
```

If you need to reset wrongTries you can call i with some arbitrary values as for example

```
drawHangman( " ", ' ' );
```

If you do not want to call the functions the way I showed above that to reset wrongTries then you can define it the following way

```
size_t drawHangman( const std::string &word = " ", char c = ' ' )
{ 
    static size_t wrongTries = 0;

    if ( word.find( c ) != std::string::npos )
    {
        return ( wrongTries = 0 );
    }
    else
    {
        return ( ++wrongTries );
    }
}
```

and you can call it simply as

```
drawHangman();
```

to reset wrongTries.

If you need the case-insensitive search then you can use standard algorithm `std::find_if`. For example

```
#include <algorithm>

size_t drawHangman( const std::string &word, char c )
{ 
    static size_t wrongTries = 0;

    suto it = std::find_if( word.begin(), word.end(),
                            [=]( char t ) { return ( std::toupper( t ) == std::toupper( c ) ); } );

    if ( it != word.end() )
    {
        return ( wrongTries = 0 );
    }
    else
    {
        return ( ++wrongTries );
    }
}
```

On the other hand if you need to count all cases when a character is not presen in a string you can write the function the following way

```
int drawHangman( const std::string &word = "", char c = '\0' )
{ 
    static int wrongTries = 0;

    if ( word.empty() )
    {
         wrongTries = 0;
         return wrongTries;
    }

    if ( word.find( c ) != std::string::npos )
    {
        return ( -wrongTries );
    }
    else
    {
        return ( ++wrongTries );
    }
}
```

So you can check whether a character is present in the string the following way

```
if ( drawHangman( SomeString, SomeChar ) <= 0 )
{
   // the character is found in the string
}
else
{
   // the character is not found in the string
}
```

And if you need to reset wrongTries you can call the function as

```
drawHangman();
```

Comment: While this does sound more like what he is trying to do, It would probably be better to avoid creating local static variables like this, especially when it comes to 'resetting' the game so the player can try again.

Comment: @BlackBird  I do not see any problem.

Comment: Start a game, wrongTries = 0.  Finish that game, without closing the application, start the next game, new word, wrongTries = X where X is the number of wrong guesses in the first game.

Comment: @BlackBird See my post one more.

Comment: I see that now, sorry my example with the next game does fail.  However, I am confused why you would even want the static local variable in the first place instead of just a local?

Comment: @BlackBird As I understand it has to preserve its value between two successive calls when the letter is not present in a word.

Comment: I guess there may be different ways to play hangman, but this logic could be wrong in this scenario:  "horse" is the word.  User chooses "a" wrongTries = 1.   User chooses "b" wrongTries = 2.   User chooses "h" wrongTries = 0.  In this case, the way I am familiar with the game, the wrongTries should still be 2.  Which is why I suggested in my answer to keep the attempted letters in a container, and a second function to count the misses.  Also then the attempted letters could be displayed to the user.

Comment: This counts the number of times the function is called consecutively with characters which are not in the string.  I'm not saying it's wrong, but how did you come to the conclusion that this is what the OP was trying to do? Considering that in a game of hangman (at least in any version I've ever played), incorrect letter guesses will be interspersed with correct letter guesses, I can't see how this particular stat will be useful.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley  "but how did you come to the conclusion that this is what the OP was trying to do?" - I am sorry but it is very silly question. Having the code in the original post and neither decription I supposed one possible approach and nothing more.

Comment: Well I am a silly person, so I ask silly questions. And I have this strange notion that when someone answers a question, it tends to mean they understood the question. Silly me. (Or is it the OP's question you were referring to as silly?)

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley If ypu have own idea how to answer the question why so not write it? Write the answer that you think is a correct answer. It isit your right.

Comment: Chnossos already answered the question, as far as I can tell.  And if that is not the answer, then I have no idea what the question is.  It seemed as if you had some other idea what the question is, which is why I asked how you came to that understanding of what the question is.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley Then what do you bother?!

Answer (score 1):

It is going to be case sensitive, so if wordA = "space" **(and I will be assuming the word is all lowercase already)** and you look for a 'C' you will not find a 'C'  Looking for a 'c' would find a 'c' though.

You can use [std::tolower](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) to make sure the trY character is lower cased, *again assuming wordA is lowercase already*.*

```
bool IsValidLetter(char trY, const std::string& wordA)
{
    if (wordA.find(std::tolower(trY)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Notice I removed the wrongTries counter in this situation because you are simply testing (at this point) if the letter exists in the word.

Then you would want to keep a container, probably a vector, of all the letters that have been tried so far and this could be useful pseudo-code.

```
int CountWrongLetters(attemptedLetters, wordA)
{
    int wrong = 0;
    foreach letter in attemptedLetters
    {
        if (IsValidLetter(letter, wordA) == false)
        {
            wrong++;
        }
    }
    return wrong;
}
```

Somewhere else would handle the logic to draw each part of the hangman display based on the number returned, as well as the logic to end the game.

Comment: Thank you!!
Helped a lot :)